# How to save a custom chart types

Tags: 2010, chart-web-part

I'm working on sharepoint 2010. I want to create a lot of charts in my site. all those charts must have the same appearance. I tested to just do a copy paste of my first chart but it doesn't seem to work very well. The charts don't display the right values. So my idea is to add a custom chart type. In the chart customization wizard, at the beginning, we have to select a chart type. There is a tab called "Custom Chart Types" which only display the current appearance. I guess there is a way to add other custom chart type but I don't find it...

Thanks!

Comment: How did you copy and paste your charts?

Comment: Are you talking about a chart web part? 

You cannot copy and paste any charts or business data web parts. They render as images.

Please add more information to your question, like the type of web part it is, if it is a third party web part or not.